# Bought a new Galaxy S5 New Edition 11 of January 2016,Evening February 05, put in silent mode to sleep,morning of Feb. 6 , phone dead

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

Bought a new Galaxy S5 New Edition( G903M/DS ) 11 of January 2016,Evening February 05, put in silent mode to sleep,morning of Feb. 6 , phone dead, will not start for Beans, removed Battery several times, took to store Tech. no go, told to contact Samsung ? Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a phone bought and activated in the USA:

For a phone that new, I'd certainly start with the seller or provider.  If you're getting that "not our problem" response from the store where you bought it (where you *should* be able to return the phone as defective, for a full refund or exchange to a new -- **not refurbished** phone of the same model), call the tech support line for the provider.  They should be your first point of contact if you bought the phone from them.